# Why is my device not applicable for the app configuration in android studio

Tags: android-studio

[image: Device not selectable]

[image: Flutter location]

[image: SDK Location]

I have tried following similar questions but I cannot get this to work. I have uploaded pictures of my SDK location and my flutter location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not running the `app` configuration instead you are running the `java1App` Configuration which is a Java class and is not compitable with android phones configuration so click on the `java1App` configuration dropdown and select `app` configuration and hit run it will work